# In Drupal Commerce how can you turn product select box options into images?

Tags: 7, commerce, forms

As seen in the image below, how can I turn the product dropdown options into selectable images instead? Is there a module for this or does this have to be done via js/css?

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried this with Commerce, but some modules will allow you to write HTML directly into the select options.  This will break the translation system, but it's worth a shot if your site has only one language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need images (not just colored blocks) as commerce product options take a look at [commerce_options_as_images](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_options_as_images)

I've created this module and use in on my projects.

Answer (score 2):

ok seems that this module does the trick:

https://drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes

> This module provides a "Rendered term" attribute mode, that shows the
>   rendered term instead of a radio button (degrades to a normal radio
>   button when JS is off) on the add to cart form.
>
> Example usage: 0) Enable this module. 1) Create a Color vocabulary,
>   add a text field called "Color" that will hold hex values. Go to the
>   "Manage Display" screen of that vocabulary, click the tab called "Add
>   to Cart form - Attribute", enable only the color field (with the label
>   hidden, and using the "Color" formatter). 2) Create several terms with
>   matching hex colors (Black: #000000, White: #ffffff, etc). 3) Add a
>   Color taxonomy_term_reference field to a product type. 4) When you add
>   the color field on the product type, tick the checkbox "Enable this
>   field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms." and
>   select "rendered term" as option of the "Attribute selection widget".
>
> The Add To Cart form will now show the colors. Of course, imagefields
>   can be used instead of "textfields holding hex values" rendered as
>   images.

Comment: That's the module I'd recommend. Check out commerce kickstart to see an example of configuration